# Gradle sync failed - after update Android Studio to 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Absolutely nothing helped that someone had previously found a similar problem. 
Update project file build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also update dependencies and buildToolsVersion to `'28.0.3'`

But still Gradle sync failed!!

Has anyone solved this problem after update Android Studio to 3.2?

Addition - my app build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    lintOptions {
        tasks.lint.enabled = false
    }
    flavorDimensions "local"
    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 55
        versionName "2.0.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {
           ...
        }
        mytest {
            ...
        }
        local {
           ...
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.patloew.rxlocation:rxlocation:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
    implementation 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:1.1.9'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.4.1'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.4.1'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.3.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation project(path: ':sdk')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repository.jetbrains.com/all"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also Android Studio logs if it helps:

```
2018-10-04 11:32:09,079 [ thread 19]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'xxx'. 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,083 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,242 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 23 Platform' (/Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk) to module 'sdk' 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,263 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform' (/Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk) to module 'app' 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,279 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,282 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,286 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,289 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,292 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,296 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,299 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,303 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.3/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,309 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,313 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,317 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.0-rc2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,321 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,324 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,326 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,330 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/docs/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,333 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,337 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/gapid/3/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,340 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,344 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/instantapps/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,347 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,350 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,352 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,354 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,358 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,361 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/patcher/v4/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,363 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,367 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-18/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,370 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,372 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,375 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-24/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,377 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,380 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,383 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,385 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,388 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-P/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,390 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-25/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,422 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-26/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,425 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-27/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,428 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-28/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,432 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-19/google_apis/armeabi-v7a/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,435 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-22/google_apis/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,439 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,442 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-25/google_apis/arm64-v8a/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,445 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-25/google_apis/armeabi-v7a/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,450 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,452 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis/x86_64/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,455 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-26/google_apis_playstore/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,458 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-27/google_apis/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,460 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,463 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,466 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,468 [ thread 18]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/nico/Library/Android/sdk/tools/package.xml 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,585 [ thread 19]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed (10 s 350 ms) 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,598 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2018-10-04 11:32:09,598 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project '/Users/nico/android/navek/xxx' xxx
2018-10-04 11:32:09,610 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,038 [ thread 21]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 2ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,068 [ thread 21]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 30ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,130 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0,007 s. 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,133 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,133 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0,003 s. 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,133 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 0,000 s. 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,133 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0,000 s. 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,134 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0,001 s. 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,134 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,134 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,135 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,135 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0,001 s. 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,138 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-10-04 11:32:10,138 [ thread 21]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0,000 s.
```

Comment: any error logs ?

Comment: Please post your app specific build.gradle and error logs if there are any.

Comment: only in Event Logs - Gradle sync failed (9 s 608 ms)

Comment: Open Build View from the bottom-left bar, inside it there is a vertical left bar, make "Toggle View" which is first button as active, and paste here the results, it might contains useful information

Comment: Another thing, if you upgraded to Android 28, I advice you to migrate to AndroidX, In Android 3.2 Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: Have you tried invalidate cache restart? You can try deleting ".gradle" folder in your project too!

Comment: yes of course, not working

Comment: Migrate to AndroidX - also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main cause why gradle sync failed - in app build.gradle, block dependencies, need change versions from 28.0.3 to 28.0.0 and gradle sync succesfull, but faced the following problem [Error during Sync: Broken pipe - after update Android Studio 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647358/error-during-sync-broken-pipe-after-update-android-studio-3-2)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes i just copy the gradle information from last project that worked and use it for new project, sometimes the lastest buildToolVersion will fail, try to reduce the version. 
Some other stupid solutions but sometimes work like a charm: check the internet, change android studio to offline work mode, keep clicking try again until the world end

Answer (score 0):

Examine your Manifest for Problems.  In my case it was {android:minSdkVersion} and other fields that weren't supposed to be in [manifest] for they should be set in [build.gradle].