# Error during Sync: Broken pipe - after update Android Studio 3.2, 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After update Android Studio to 3.2 and solve problem with sync gradle [Gradle sync failed - after update Android Studio to 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642075/gradle-sync-failed-after-update-android-studio-to-3-2?noredirect=1#comment92219515_52642075)  - i cant install apk -

Event Log:

```
Error during Sync: Broken pipe
Session 'app': Error Installing APK
```

Has anyone solved this problem?
What mean - Broken pipe? And why it happen?

Additional: it happen only on real device, on emulator install app successful

Comment: I think it happens when connection b/w emulator/device is lost to the android studio

Comment: in my case it happen only on device, on emulator install successful

Comment: Could you try deleting the previous installed app then trying to install it again?

Comment: yes, not helped

Comment: Still facing the same issue in Android Studio 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem - in my case I found in Activity Monitor on my Mac several processes of **adb** and kill force all processes until stayed **1 adb** processe and it helped.

**EDIT**: try in terminal comands :

```
adb kill server
adb start server
```

It help to restart your adb, I have to do it all the time on Android Studio =(

**EDIT-2**: also magic way to fix:

```
adb install -r -t apk_debug.apk
```

And then just "**Run app**" from android studio