# Nativescript builds are starting to hang

Tags: angular, nativescript, econnrefused

I've started encountering hangs during my nativescript builds for Android. Yesterday, I got hangs after installing both a plugin and a javascript library. Today, I have had ECONNREFUSED errors when pushing the build to a device via USB as well as just hangs where the build just stops. It seems like it is losing the connection to the device or the device is refusing the connection.

I can solve it sometimes by unplugging the device and reconnecting, clearing the platforms folder, or just rebooting my dev box. This is a huge pain. The project is fairly large. Are there size constraints to an app? Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I might be suddenly having these errors?

Comment: Are you getting the same issue with Android Emulator ?

Comment: I just launched it to the emulator without a problem, but that's not conclusive because the problem is intermittent. I'll work on the emulator for a while and see if the same problems crop up. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The errors do not appear to be happening with the emulator. I've been banging on it and rebuilding for over an hour without any of the above errors.

Comment: Since you are not getting issues with emular, it might be because of some antivirus program on your computer, which might be restricting some communication with the device through USB.

Comment: I disabled anti-virus and the firewall, and still getting the ECONNREFUSED. But obviously there is something interfering with comms that happened yesterday. I'll see if I can track down any changes when I return. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Pushing builds to the emulator this morning and encountered "Error is: Sync operation is taking too long" which resulted in stopping webpack. Then the console showed: "System.err: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe". I'm not sure how I can have a broken pipe when this is the only emulator running.

Comment: May be this can resolve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647358/error-during-sync-broken-pipe-after-update-android-studio-3-2

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not. I did find some version mismatches between nativescript and plugins, and fixed them. But it did not solve the problem.